# How do I make rememberSaveable work inside movableContentOf?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I made two similar navigation `@Composable`s with a slot for content, one of them is used depending on the screen size class. I also use `rememberSaveable` inside the content to handle screen rotation. The problem is, without `movableContentOf`, their state is handled as separate, but with it, the saved state is gone after every screen rotation. A simplified example:

```kotlin
Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
) {

    val content = remember {
        movableContentOf {
            var a by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            Checkbox(a, { a = it })
            var b by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
            Checkbox(b, { b = it })
        }
    }

    var switch by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Checkbox(switch, { switch = it })
    if (switch) Row { content() } else Column { content() }

}
```

Mode switching works just fine, but only the upper checkbox keeps its state after screen rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intended behaviour: you create `movableContentOf` inside `remember`, which means it's gonna be recreated on rotation.

You can store it inside a view model, but if you need to do so, you can store your data there as well, which makes storing `movableContentOf` redundant: in this case, re-creating it in `remember` is perfectly fine.